# Storing username in cookie to increase cacheability?

Tags: security, cookies, account

Using: PHP, Symfony 1.4, Doctrine, sfGuard

I have a site where the majority of pages could be cached as full HTML pages.  But there is the traditional 'user account toolbar' that appears at the top right of most sites (shows the logged in username, logout link etc.)

This obviously prevents the page from being fully cached as HTML so I plan on outputting the page as standard HTML and adding in the username etc. after page load, via Javascript.

When the user logs in, I will create an extra cookie storing just the username.  Javascript can then check if the cookie exists and create the account toolbar.  The username will only be used for display purposes.  In order to actually log in the users will have to go through the normal login page, using their password etc.

I've searched for blog posts etc on this but not found much. Can anyone identify any security or other concerns with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the user name is only used for display purposes you should be golden.  Alternatly you could use an XHR to grab the username from PHP's $_SESSION.

My concerns are that you'd be using the user name to authenticate that user.  Or using the user name as a key to access your cache,  where by changing the user name would give an attacker access to another's cache.

Comment: Thanks Rook.  The sessions are stored by a separate key so changing the username in the cookie would have no effect other than changing the name displayed in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should never, ever store anything sensitive in a cookie.  To me, that includes usernames.

Comment: The usernames are public, anyone can see them on the site

Comment: most apps are like SO,  in that they don't obscure usernames. You can just iterate over the primary key and enumerate all usernames.  The only exception would be sites like paypal.  Although XHR would be better for this solution.

Comment: I like that idea, Rook.  I don't mind usernames not being locked down, but to me they should never be in a cookie, as it's half of what an attacker needs if they're not a member of the system.  Your idea is a good one, leave the username visible on the site, after looking it up via primary key.  As long as whatever's stored in the cookie is unrelated to login credentials, I'm fine with it.  A lot of sites store session info, which although there's a risk with that as well, it's at least transitory.

Comment: When a user logs in, I store the UserID and AccessToken in a cookie. I recently decided to store the Username as well, because it's displayed with every request.  Having a snapshot of UserID+Username could have other uses as well.  Anyway, when restoring a session from a cookie when session is lost, I load the UserID/AccessToken from the cookie and then validate the combination against the database. By including the Username as well, it's just saving trips to the database and saving trips to the web server, so I see no harm and much benefit from storing the username in the cookie.